# Can all connected graphs be embedded on a closed, compact 2-Manifold?

Tags: graph-theory, compact-manifolds

I know that there are spherical (planar) graphs such as $K_4$,and toroidal graphs such as $k_7$, but I was wondering if given any connected graph $G$, there exists a closed, compact 2-Manifold $M$ such that $G$ can be embedded in $M$?  If so, does the smallest possible genus of $M$ or whether or not $M$ is orientable tell us any properties of $G$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finite graphs, the answer is yes. 
(For infinite graphs, your embedding of the vertex set on a compact surface will necessarily have accumulation points, which is a bit of a mess.)

To see this, just draw the graph in the sphere, such that only two edges ever cross at a single point. By compactness, we can do this by just wiggling the edges a bit to prevent triple crossings. For each crossing, add a handle for one of the crossing edges to make a 'bridge' for the one edge to go over the other (in the diagram, the added handle, viewed from above, is in blue).
[image]

Note that this construction does not give the lowest genus surface possible for an embedding, it's just an easy argument to show such a surface exists.

The minimum genus is a useful piece of information. For each genus, there is a finite set of forbidden minor obstructions, per the Robertson-Seymour Theorem (much like $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ are obstructions for embedding on the plane or sphere). 
The genus also bounds the [chromatic number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MapColoring.html) of the graph (so an analog of the four-colour theorem holds for any compact surface). 
It is also sometimes possible to create more efficient algorithms for graphs of bounded genus than for arbitrary graphs.

I don't know anything regarding orientability however.

Comment: For the Robertson-Seymour Theorem, if a graph $G$ is a forbidden minor obstruction of a genus $K$, does that mean it is not a forbidden minor obstruction for any other genus?

Comment: For the orientable case, if $G$ is forbidden on genus $K$, it is also forbidden for any genus less than $K$. I'm not sure how things work in the non-orientable case, I'd assume it's similar.

Comment: What I meant to say was that if there is a graph $G$ that was on the minimal list of forbidden minor obstructions for graphs of genus $K$ and $K+n$, then by your handle bar argument above, this tells me that the graph has $n+1$ unavoidable crossings when embedded on a surface of genus $K$.  So if we removed one edge from $n$ of those crossings (call this graph $G’$), we’d still have one unavoidable crossing, making the list of forbidden minor obstructions of genus $K$ non-minimal since we don’t need $G$ in the list, only $G’$.  So the minimal list for any two genus must be unique.  Correct?